# Wand to ivalidate the session after 10 minutes in struts

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-timeout

I have written code using struts. I want to invalidate the session if the user is idle for 10 minutes. I want to write the code in servlets but not in jsp. can anyone suggest?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried , which will SO members to suggest you the solution. As we can post you the entire solution

Comment: It is almost impossible to give help with the provided information. Try telling us what you have already tried, perhaps show us the code you have and be specific with what part you need help with. Stack overflow is not meant as a consultancy firm doing your work but a community where you can make use of others knowledge. But be specific and show us that you have made an effort and I am sure that you soon will get help with your problem. With respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `web.xml` put

```
<session-config>  
    <session-timeout>  
        10
    </session-timeout>  
</session-config>
```